# Wordpress post in sidebar

Tags: wordpress

As i choose Wordpress for my CMS, and my client love it... i like to be able to customize a little my template. The WYSIWYG editor is easy ans people love it, because it look like word. It's easy to include picture and make links so it's a win win situation.

My question, i like to be able to take some page or page (i prefer page) and let people create small content page.. those page will be taken and put into sidebar or top section or in the footer like the 3 colum style footer info...

I know it can be done with test wiadget, but link and styling is too complicated (HTML)... so, how to take page and get it into widget box or something like that..

google, search, wordpress, plugin have been check... no luck

Anybody have a solution , code or plugin that do just that ?

- wp 3.x compatible ! please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [query_posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-posts/) widget. It will permit you to basically insert a post or a particular page into a sidebar as a widget - as you intended.  It doesn't require you to reinvent the wheel and put a wysiwyg into a widget option.

Best part - images, etc work with this natively.  If you need more sidebars (even if they're header/footer linear bars in actuality), just create them in your functions.php.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few plugins out there that allow for a rich text editor version of the Text Widget. I personally have not tried them, but here's a few examples:

[Rich Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-widget/)

[WYSIWYG Text Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wysiwyg-text-widget/)

[Rich Text Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-text-widget/)

It looks like at least one of these isn't WordPress 3 compatible, but this should give you an idea of what's out there.